# check if object property are all false

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to check if all certain properties of an object are set to a specific value. But how can I achieve this in a good way?

the output (`data.items`) looks like this:

```
0: {id_menu: 1234, menunummer: "1", menu_naam: "test1", permission: "Y"}
1: {id_menu: 1235, menunummer: "2", menu_naam: "test2", permission: "Y"}
2: {id_menu: 1236, menunummer: "2", menu_naam: "test3", permission: "Y"}
```

but how can I check if permission property of all data.items are set to `"Y"`

I tried this:

```
 for(var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++){
    console.log('permissionMENU',data.items[i].permission);
    if(data.items[i].permissie === "N"){
       console.log('WORKS');
   }
}
```

But this check every item seperatly how can I check if all items their permission are set to "Y"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```
data.items.every(item => item.permission === 'Y')
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `data.items` is an array, you can try to use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

```
data.items.filter(x => x.permission === 'Y').length === data.items.length
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let dataItems = Object.values(data.items);
dataItems.filter(dataItem => dataItem.permission === 'Y').length === dataItems.length;
```

The Object.values function will give you an array with just the objects. after that we filter through them just returning the items when the permission is Y and we compare that length with the actual length.

(Haven't actually tested this code but this should work)

Answer (score -1):

from your array you can use [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), which will give a new array of objects which satisfies the condition.

use a if else condition to check whether the filteredarray has any elements if 
filteredarray.length ===0 there is no objects which means every object property permission has **Y**.

if the length is !=0 (not equal to zero), some objects property permission has some another value which means **N**. So you can print out the elements.

See the below code. I hope this will solve your  issue.

**Note**: i have added one more object which has the property of permission has **N** in order to show the else case how it works. You can remove the object.

```js
let arr = [{id_menu: 1234, menunummer: "1", menu_naam: "test1", permission: "Y"},
{id_menu: 1235, menunummer: "2", menu_naam: "test2", permission: "Y"},
{id_menu: 1236, menunummer: "2", menu_naam: "test3", permission: "Y"},
{id_menu: 1236, menunummer: "2", menu_naam: "test3", permission: "N"}
]

let filteredArr = arr.filter(o => o.permission != "Y")

if(filteredArr.length === 0){
console.log("All properties has permission as Yes(Y)")
}else{
console.log("Some properties have permission has No(N) which are", filteredArr)
}
```